# Apply transform of your own function in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have pandas dataframe on which I need to some data manipulation, the following code provide me the average of column "Variable" group by "Key":

```
df.groupby('key').Variable.transform("mean")
```

The advantage of using "transform" is that it return back the result with the same index which is pretty useful.

Now, I want to have my customize function and use it within "transform" instead of "mean" more over my function need two or more column something like:

```
lambda (Variable, Variable1, Variable2): (Variable + Variable1)/Variable2
```

(actual function of mine is more complicated than this example) and each row of my dataframe has Variable,Variable1 and Variable2.

I am wondering if I can define and use such a customized function within "transform" to be able to rerun the result back with same index?

Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 2):

Don't call transform against `Variable`, call it on the grouper and then call your variables against the dataframe the function receives as argument:

```
df.groupby('key').transform(lambda x: (x.Variable + x.Variable1)/x.Variable2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is what I used: df.groupby('key').transform(lambda x: np.average(x.Variable)) but I got an error of "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object"

Comment: why not x.Variable.mean() ??

Comment: x.Variable.mean() might works but I need to use numpy function as they are more sophisticate for example weight average, std, etc. can e easily calculated using numpy functions.

Comment: All the functions you mentioned exist against pandas dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use simple

`df.Variable + df.Variable1 / df.Variable2`

There is no need to groupby. In case for example you want to divide by `df.groupby('key').Variable2.transform("mean")` you can still do it with transform as following:

`df.Variable + df.Variable1 / df.groupby('key').Variable2.transform("mean")`